# Pandas not registering individual row entries as individual column entries

Tags: pandas

Pandas thinks my 95-entry row is one single column. I don't know if it's necessary to reproduce it here, but if it is I will. I try to get the proper column info

```
df1.columns
```

and it just says I have one column. All the entries are separated by appropriate spaces, why would it be doing this? I've tried both

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('filehere')
```

and

```
df1 = pd.read_table('filehere')
```

to no success.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need to specify the `sep` (delimiter) argument of [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html) (and friends).
For example:

```
df = pd.read_csv('filehere', sep=r'\s+')
```

*Here sep is the regular expression "at least one space".*

Comment: Yep, that fixed it. I had misplaced a ' in my coding. Thank you, for the 100th time @AndyHayden.